# Enable session replication in Oracle Commerce CSA 11.2

Tags: jboss, atg, session-replication, atg-dynamo, oracle-commerce

I use Oracle Commerce 11.2 and CSA and I'm trying to enable session replication.

I have `/atg/dynamo/Configuration.backingUpSessions == true` and `/atg/dynamo/Configuration.sessionBackupServerPropertyList` contains the following list:

```
/SessionConfirmationNumberHolder.sessionConfirmationNumber,
/atg/userprofiling/ProfileFailService.uidForFailover,
/atg/userprofiling/ProfileFailService.dataSource,
/atg/dynamo/security/UserFailService.savedPersonae,
/atg/commerce/ShoppingCart.restorableOrders,
/atg/commerce/ShoppingCart.returnRequest,
/atg/userprofiling/ProfileFailService.activePromotions,
/atg/commerce/catalog/comparison/ProductList.items,
/atg/commerce/gifts/GiftlistFormHandler.eventName,
/atg/userprofiling/ProfileFailService.failedOverSecurityStatus
```

Also I configured session replication on JBoss EAP 6.2.

It works properly, but sometimes(chance is about 50%) after a user logged in, his profile remains transient and all of his properties is `null`. On UI it looks like this
[image]

If i set `/atg/dynamo/Configuration.backingUpSessions` to `false` it works fine. So this issue is definitely related to session backup.
Also this issue persists even if there is only one jboss instance.